# Return value in Python for Loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Hi want to return value after for loop. My code is -

```
def asd():
    data.append("a")
    data.append("b")
    for i in range(0,2):
        value = data[i]
        return value
```

I am expecting to return both a and b when calling the function but it is returning only b. Is there any other method. Thanks in advance

Comment: So if I write `answer = asd()`, then `answer == ("a", "b")` should be true?

Comment: No the value returned is answer = "b". But I want like how you stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a very pressing reason for doing things this way, this example can be simplified to

```
def asd():
    return 'a', 'b'
```

Comment: There's almost certainly more to it in the real application. We ask people to post minimal examples that demonstrate the problem, don't penalize him for leaving out unnecessary details.

Comment: Cmon man. You know this not is what he wants ;)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But its not good to act oversmart. I had a condition where the append is outside the function but i needed both the values to print "in loop" and not together. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but it will help you to find your mistake.

The `=` is an assignment operator. The value provided behind the `=` is assigned to the variable in front of it, e.g. `a = 3` means that a now carries the value 3.

Now two easy questions

```
a=3
a=5
print a
```

Which value gets printed?

Similarly,

```
for i in range(100):
    a = i
print a
```

What value gets printed?

Comment: You've explained somewhat why his program doesn't work. Are you going to give him any hint on how to do what he actually wants?

Comment: @Barmar: If I knew what he wants I could certainly give a hint. In principle `return data` would be enough, but since he has added a loop without telling us, what the loop should do, he would need to find out the solution for himself.